# How do I ignore /usr/include in Coverity Scan?

Tags: coverity

I've set up a project to use [Coverity Scan](https://scan.coverity.com/).

Under **Analysis Settings→Project Components** I have

```
Component name  Pattern              Ignore in analysis     
cxxopts         .*/src/cxxopts.hpp         Yes  
STL             /usr/include/c++/.*        Yes
```

but still when I go to **View defects** I see 9 issues, all from files like `/usr/include/c++/5.4.1/functional`. How do I actually exclude them?

---

Confusingly, the **Overview** tab shows

```
12 Total defects
2 Outstanding
7 Dismissed
3 Fixed
```

even though **View defects** shows 9 issues (is that the 7+2? Why are some outstanding and some dismissed, when all should be ignored?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a regex pattern, in which case the "++" likely needs some form of escaping. I'm not sure which form, because I don't know how the strings are being interpreted or what kind of regex syntax is being used, but some variant of the following should work:

```
/usr/include/c\+\+/.*
/usr/include/c\\+\\+/.*
/usr/include/c\\\+\\\+/.*
```

If none of these work, I'd suggest contacting scan-admin@coverity.com (listed as the contact email for questions on the scan website).

This would also explain why the overview shows results from these files at all.

Comment: Doh, how did I miss that … `/usr/include/.*` at least seems to exclude the stuff, though I still haven't found out which escaping to use (even `[+]` didn't have an effect from what I could tell).

Comment: A bit too soon, `/usr/include/c\+\+/.*` seems to work :-)