# How can I set up up components in Coverity Scan

Tags: coverity

I am trying to set up Coverity Scan for my Open Source project. I can produce a local build and upload it fine, all of that works. But I am unable to create components using Coverity's web UI.

I tried adding components under the project's analysis settings. When I add a component, it shows up in the table, but when I click on "Save Changes", the page reloads and the component I just created is gone. The following screenshot illustrates what I see right before clicking on "Save Changes":

[image]

I could not find anyone else having this problem when I searched for it. Coverity has a video tutorial explaining how to set up components, but they do it using the Connect System UI, and the option to add components is not present for me there.

Comment: You just found someone else with the same problem (me!), but unfortunately I don't have the solution. You do get a star and an upvote for taking the time to ask the question. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @JaimeSoto . The fact that this question gets not traction makes me wonder if the problem isn't something in my project. Maybe we can compare notes to see if there is something odd our projects have in common?

Comment: The initial cov-int archive I uploaded to Coverity Scan took several months to be analyzed, even though it's for [a small C library](https://github.com/Simverge/pdal-c). My guess is that a major server migration they had in January caused a big backlog. It looks like the components issue happened before in [2017](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46216894/448455). I found a [GitHub project](https://github.com/philippegabriel/coverity) that uses its SOAP API, so I'm hoping that project could lead us to the solution.

Comment: Thanks, the SOAP client thing is interesting. I'll take a look at that when I get back to this issue. My archive was analyzed very quickly, btw.

Comment: Great news! You can now set up components in Coverity Scan. I learned about this fix from a [related thread in the Synopsys forums](https://community.synopsys.com/s/question/0D53400003pnL0i/getting-the-were-sorry-but-something-went-wrong-error?s1oid=00D3000000007Mm&t=1568338317683&s1nid=0DB340000008S5F&emkind=chatterCommentNotification&s1uid=0053400000C4tPC&emtm=1568225976743&fromEmail=1&s1ext=0) and confirmed it in [my project](https://scan.coverity.com/projects/simverge-pdal-c).